# Python xls: Copying only non-hidden rows to new Workbook and save

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlwt

I'm working on a script to copy only non-hidden rows from one file to a new workbook. Right now I have this:

```
 import xlrd
 import xlwt
 from xlrd import open_workbook

 wb = open_workbook('input.xls', formatting_info=True)

 wb_sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

 newBook = xlwt.Workbook()
 newSheet = newBook.add_sheet("no_hidden")

 idx = 0
 for row_idx in range(1, wb_sheet.nrows):
     hidden = wb_sheet.rowinfo_map[row_idx].hidden
     if(hidden is not True):
        for col_index, cell_value in enumerate(wb_sheet.row[row_idx]):
            newSheet.write(idx, col_index, cell_value)
            idx = idx+1
 newBook.save("test.xls")
```

However, I get an error saying this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "delete.py", line 16, in <module>
    for col_index, cell_value in enumerate(wb_sheet.row[row_idx]):
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

I think I'm handling the `wb_sheet.row[]`-object wrong, but I cannot figure out how to achieve what I want at this point. Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.sheet.Sheet.row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, modify your code as below, hope this may be helpful.

```
import xlrd
import xlwt
from xlrd import open_workbook

wb = open_workbook('input.xls', formatting_info=True)

wb_sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

newBook = xlwt.Workbook()
newSheet = newBook.add_sheet("no_hidden")

idx = 0
for row_idx in range(0, wb_sheet.nrows):
    hidden = wb_sheet.rowinfo_map[row_idx].hidden
    if(hidden==0):
        for col_index, cell_obj in enumerate(wb_sheet.row(row_idx)):
            newSheet.write(idx, col_index, cell_obj.value)
        idx = idx+1
newBook.save("test1.xls")
```

instead of wb_sheet.row[row_idx] it should be wb_sheet.row(row_idx) and
it returns cell object, at the time of writing into other excel file
cell_obj.value should be written.

Hope this may help.

Comment: Nice, thanks. Regarding data-size, I have an additional issue that I can only parse .xls-files with only 65553 rows possible. How can I rewrite that code in order to open .xlsx? formatting_info=True does only work on .xls

Answer (score 1):

From documentation row is mehtod

> row(rowx)
>
> ```
> Returns a sequence of the Cell objects in the given row.
> ```

Just change this part of your code:

```
  for col_index, cell_value in enumerate(wb_sheet.row(row_idx)):
```

Same errors:

```py
 def a():pass
 a[1]  # TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Yes, my fault. However I accept the other answer as it seems to be a more complete answer not only pointing at the issue, which may be more helpful to others. That is not meant to downvote your answer or be insulting as what you write is absolutely correct.